# using openid with flask(Python Framework) getting following error: OpenID authentication error

Tags: python, flask, openid

I am using Openid for authentication in Flask framework. Following is my code for login View.

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
        return oid.try_login(form.openid.data, ask_for = ['nickname', 'email'])
    print "Errors of Openid:"+oid.fetch_error()
    return render_template('login.html', 
        title = 'Sign In',
        form = form,
        providers = app.config['OPENID_PROVIDERS'])
```

This piece of code redirect me to google.com. When i am redirected back to my site (After providing my credentials ). I receive following error:"OpenID authentication error"

Comment: please add some info on the libraries you're using and a full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the time/timezone of the server and error was no longer there.